# Setting Up A Single Stylesheet Depending on Locale

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, localization

I have some translated text that I want to do absolute positioning.  I have the word NEW in English and NOUVEAU in French.  I want the word to appear in the center below a graphic.  Since the words are different lengths I thought the best way (ugly) would be to do absolute positioning.  I would like to set left: to a value for NEW and another value for NOUVEAU depending on if the locale is en or fr.

Here is the code in my view:

```
<p class="header-new1"><%= "#{t :new_landing}" %></p>
```

Here is my current CSS code which puts NOUVEAU where I want it positioned:

```
.header-new1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: @red;
    font-size: 143%;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 450px;
    left: 652px;
}
```

I have read a lot of different solutions but none that fit my situation.  My hope is to find a way where I will not have to create separate CSS code for each locale and check the locale in my view.  If there is cleaner way to do this I would sure appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me get this straight:

You have an image (graphic), under which you want to center a `p`? Why don't you give the `p` the same width as the image/graphic and add `text-align: center` to your css. That should do the trick. Or am I getting this completely wrong?

Comment: The image I'm trying to center the text under has absolute positioning.  So I need to use absolute positioning for the text.  My hope was to somehow determine the locale and set the left css position.  I decided to use id for each locale to set the left position.  My view is ugly but it's working.  I had tried html[lang=locale] for each locale in my application but it did not work.  I'm sure there is something that I missed somewhere but my ugly solution is working.

Comment: But you always know where the image is positioned and what dimensions it has? If so, my solution still works. Just give your `p` the same `left` and `width` attributes as your image, calculate the `top`, and center the text.

If the image size is dynamic, use Javascript to calculate the correct `left`, `top` and `width` attributes.